# Search for value in another table if can not be find in table 1 sql server

Tags: sql

I have two tables

Table A

Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4

12134            3525           KeyNo           RefNo

Table B

Column 1    Column 2    Column 4

12134       3525        RefNo

Need to search the value of Column 1 and Column 2 from Table A based on the Column 3

in some cases, the value of Column 1 and Column 2 in Table A is "BLANK" and can be found the same value in Table B based on the Column 4

Please advise with example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to select "column 1" and "column 2" based on "column 4" key either from Table A or Table B?

Use UNION, or 2 consecutive SELECTs.

Comment: Can you please give an example because it's not giving me what I am looking for? I want to read the record from Table B based on the Column 4 from the another table.

Comment: Maybe you could amend the initial question with example table contents and the query results you'd like to see?